# Is $X$ always diagonal matrix when $e^{iX} = 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $e^{iX} = 1$. Then is $X$ always a diagonal matrix? What happens if $X$ is constrained to be a hermitian matrix?

Comment: For $e^{iX}=1$, $X$ *has* to be hermitian. In general if $A^2=1$, then $X=2 \pi A$ will work. $A$ doesn't have to be diagonal, see the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could have
$$X=2\pi\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}.$$
That is diagonal! But if we take a conjugate of $X$ that will still work, say
$$X=2\pi\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$$
instead.